# How do I write a script that restarts an application that runs in the Terminal on Mac server after the machine reboots?

Tags: macos, server, restart, launchd

I have an application that normally runs in Terminal. This requires changing directory to the application directory [cd /mydirectory] and launching the application ./PurplesoftServer

I am struggling with writing a launch script to restart the application if the server restarts for any reason. I saved the script in /Library/LaunchAgents

**This is my script:**

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
     <dict>
          <key>Label</key>
          <string>PSM.Restart</string>

          <key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Users/stephenjay/Documents/HW/HW Customers/ACME server 200814</string>          
    <string>./PurpleSoftServer</string>     
</array>

          <key>RunAtLoad</key>
          <true/>
     </dict>
</plist>```
````

I also ran the following commands in Terminal in an effort to load the script:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/PSM.Restart.plist
sudo launchctl start PurplesoftServer
```

Everything appears to run - after I gave ownership of the plist to **root:wheel**

However, the application doesn't end up running, neither after running the Sudo commands nor after actually restarting the Mac server.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

The first item in the `ProgramArguments` array should be the path to the executable, not a directory to `cd` to. You need to use the `WorkingDirectory` key instead. Something like this:

```
...
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>./PurpleSoftServer</string>     
</array>
<key> WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>/Users/stephenjay/Documents/HW/HW Customers/ACME server 200814</string>
...
```

BTW, you'll need to use `sudo launchctl unload` to unload the bad version, then `sudo launchctl load` again to load the fixed version.

BTW2, `sudo launchctl list PSM.Restart` will give you more info about the run status of the item.